# How to display cancel button for failed uploads in fineuploader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, fine-uploader

I am using fineuploader. Some upload may fail as user try to upload duplicate file.
I see a red color and the error message from server is shown.
I am not seeing any cancel OR Remove button that would allow the user to start fresh again by selecting a new file.

I was expecting fineuploader to show cancel button on failed files but it is not.

I can add onError callback then find the right row and show the cancel or other button by adding Remove button. That sound messy solution.

That cancel button would remove that file and let user select another file.

Can I add this capability by setting options in the settings?

```
    var fileUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: $('#manual-fine-uploader')[0],
        request: {
            endpoint: 'upload/UploadFiles',                    
        },
        multiple: true,
        autoUpload: false,
        validation: {},
        text: {uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Select File'},
        callbacks: {
            onSubmit: function (id, file) {//my custom code },
            onCancel: function(id, file){ if(filesCount>=1) filesCount--;},
            onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {filesCount--;}
        },
        failedUploadTextDisplay: {
            mode: 'custom',
            maxChars: 40,
            responseProperty: 'error',
            enableTooltip: true
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fine Uploader only displays a cancel button while a file is uploading (as well before uploads have started if you have set the `autoUpload` option to false).  Showing a cancel button after the upload has completed seems like it would be a bit confusing to users, but I can see why you might want to display a "remove" button.

You can easily do this by adding the button to the file portion of your template.  For example, your template might look similar to this:

```html
<div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
    ...
    <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list">
        <li>
            ...
            <button class="remove-button-selector" style="display:none">Remove</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then, add a click handler to purge the file from Fine Uploader's internals & the UI:

```
$('#manual-fine-uploader').on("click", ".remove-button-selector", function() {
    var fileId = fileUploader.getId(this);

    fileUploader.cancel(fileId);
});
```

Finally, in your `onComplete` handler, show the button if the upload has failed:

```
onComplete: function(id, name, response, xhr) {
    var fileItemEl = fileUploader.getItemByFileId(id);

    if (!response.success) {
        $(fileItemEl).find(".remove-button-selector").show();
    }
}
```

Additionally, since you are already using jQuery in your project, I strongly suggest you make use of the Fine Uploader jQuery plug-in.  It will make your life a bit easier.